# How to pass the content of your columns to a dummyField in react-bootstrap-table2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I'm trying to pass the value of my columns datafield to my buttons in react-bootstrap-table2 dummyField. And I don't quite know how to do it. this is my columns datafield.

```
const columns = [
    {
      dataField: "firstName",
      text: "First Name",
    },
    {
      dataField: "middleName",
      text: "Middle Name",
    },
    {
      dataField: "lastName",
      text: "Last Name",
    },
    {
      dataField: "sex",
      text: "Sex",
      sort: true,
    },
    {
      dataField: "rootChapter",
      text: "Root Chapter",
    },
    {
      dataField: "municipalCouncil.name",
      text: "Council",
      sort: true,
    },
    {
      dataField: "batchName",
      text: "Batch Name",
      sort: true,
    },
    {
      dataField: "alias",
      text: "Alias",
    },
    {
      dataField: "actions",
      text: "Actions",
      isDummyField: true,
      formatter: (cell, row) => <MemberButtons member={columns} id={row._id} />, // Overhere is the problem
    },
  ];
```

I'm doing this because of the modal. I'm a beginner to React.js and specially to react-bootstrap-table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it works by doing this

```
{
      dataField: "actions",
      text: "Actions",
      isDummyField: true,
      formatter: (cell, row) => <MemberButtons values={row} id={row._id} />, // By passing row variable to values I got all the contents of my datafields
    },
```

Thank you for those who tried to help me.. If you found a better way to do this please dont hesitate to post it here..  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

***1st approach***: Use state to pass it to your component

```
export default class yourClassName extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
columns: [ your array data here ]
}
render(){
<yourTable/>
}
}
```

***2nd approach*** : you can use State Hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Both approaches will yield same results, you can pick the one that suits your coding style.